# Sum column values but only if specific key exists in same row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, filtering

I need to sum the `price` values of all rows where the optional check element exists.

Sample data:

```
[
    6254 => [
        'check' => 'on',
        'quantity' => 2,
        'name' => 'Testing product_special One Size',
        'total' => 15.9,
        'price' => 33.0000,
        'totalken' => 33075.9,
    ],
    6255 => [
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'Testing card',
        'total' => 113.85,
        'price' => 33.0000,
        'totalken' => 16537.95,
    ],
    6256 => [
        'check' => 'on',
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'Testing food',
        'total' => 113.85,
        'price' => 33.0000,
        'totalken' => 16537.95,
    ],
]
```

I tried `array_sum(array_column($value, 'price'))` but this sums all price values regardless of the check value.

Expected result: `66`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) in this case.

array_reduce loops through the array and uses a callback function to reduce array to a single value.

```
<?php

$totalPrice = array_reduce($myArray, function ($accumulator, $item) {
    // I'm checking 'check' key only here, you can test for 'on' value if needed
    if (isset($item['check'])) { 
        $accumulator += $item['price'];
    }
    return $accumulator;
});
```

Comment: The guy wants a single value from an array. This is what array_reduce does. Recommended from a clean code/intention perspective. But I'll remove phrase from answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply filter the array based on condition by using array_filter() function of php.

You can see the usage of array_filter() [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Here is my solution for you if you want to use condition.

```
$filteredByCheck = array_filter($value, function ($val){
           return isset($val['check']);
       });

$total = array_sum(array_column($filteredByCheck, 'price'));
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest method would be just to loop over the array and maintain a sum, use `?? ''` to default it to blank if not set...

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($value as $element )    {
    if ( ($element['check'] ?? '') == "on" )  {
        $total += $element['price'];
    }
}
```

Comment: `?? ''` what does it mean ? cant find it on google , can you explain it more for me ? so i can understand it more detail

Comment: `??` is the [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

Answer (score 0):

@aliirfaan's implementation of `array_reduce()` can be modernized and compacted as the following snippet.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CqkYB))

```
echo array_reduce(
         $array,
         fn($result, $row) =>
             $result + isset($row['check']) * $row['price']
     );
```

The above uses arrow function syntax which is available since PHP7.4. The mathematics in the return value of the custom function multiplies the price value by the `true`/`false` evaluation of `isset()` on the check column.  The boolean value is coerced to an integer automatically when used with arithmetic -- false is zero and true is one.  If the coercion is not to your liking, you can explicitly cast the boolean value using `(int)` immediately before `isset()`.